# Проблемы с циклом for

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Совершаю запросы в цикле:

```
for (int j=0;j<=15;j++) {
    Log.d(mytag,"111111");

    ...

    VKRequest request = VKApi.audio().search(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.Q, artist, 
       VKApiConst.OFFSET, 100, VKApiConst.COUNT, 100));                  
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {     
        @Override                       
        public void onComplete( VKResponse response ) {                            
            super.onComplete(response);                            
            Log.d(mytag,"222222");

            ...

        }
    }
}
```

Сначала 15 раз выводится

> 111111

, затем несколько раз

> 222222

То есть сначала проходит цикл `for` 15 раз, а только после этого выполняется запрос и работа с ним, хотя должно происходить во время цикла `for`.

Comment: Все верно, ведь на выполнение запроса нужно какое-то время.

Answer (score 1):

Вы последовательно запускаете асинхронные запросы к серверу. в 99.(9)% случаев они исполняются дольше, чем исполняется сам цикл.

Т.к. задача ваша асинхронная, т.е. исполняемая в потоке отличном о потока цикла, то следующая итерация цикла будет исполнена вне зависимости от процесса асинхронной задачи.

Если вам нужно последовательно выполнять задачи, то вам или надо их выполнять в том же потоке что и цикл, или запускать следующую задачу в момент окончания текущей. Для этого есть коллбэки типа onSuccess, из коих и надо запускать следующую задачу